# Insert multiple values in single cell in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have searched different [pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392717/inserting-multiple-values-in-a-single-mysql-cell). Is it possible to insert many values in single cell

[image]

Under id 475 can all values be stored like related_id=281,283,284,285,286

```
INSERT INTO LOGI (related_id)VALUES(281), (283), (284), (285), (286)
```

UPDATE1 Now if I want to update the all logi_keyword_id for logiid=613[image: Update issue]
UPDATE logi_logi_keyword SET logi_keyword_id='102' WHERE EXISTS logi_id='543' but it gives error-  #1062 - Duplicate entry '543-102' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: you should not do it. you should use another table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure if you really want to, assuming `related_id` is a `varchar` or `text` column type...

```
INSERT INTO LOGI (related_id) VALUES('281,283,284,285,286');
```

However this breaks the whole foreign key paradigm. You won't be able to run SELECT queries and join tables based on this column.

Better to create a cross-reference table. Call it `LOGI_RELATED` perhaps, with `logi_id` and `related_id` columns. Then you can have one `LOGI` record with relationships to multiple `RELATED` records.

Sounds like you may want to do some research on "many to many relationships" and improve your database design.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky I see OP asking to "insert many values in single cell." All "under id 475." That doesn't sound like multiple rows to me.

Comment: But taking a look at the problem image link they gave, you'll notice its the other way. They have a new row for every value

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky That image is the problem, not how he wants it. He wants all these values "under id 475" which is a single row.

Comment: Fair enough, that makes sense.

Comment: @jszobody you can store like this and use the explode and implode functions to get the data and merge it, but its preferable to store them in a different table with uid and related_id as two columns with foreign key on uid

Comment: @tHeSiD explode/implode work great in PHP, not so much for SQL joins

Comment: @jszobody I was talking about php, since you look like you are on php/mysql. You can store the concatenated string of ids in the field and explode it using php whenever you want, and store it again into the db with implode

Comment: @all Thanks to every body, but new table cannot be created so I have to use this table only.

Answer (score 0):

for this situation you need another table to establish a one to many relation using your table id as a foreign key.
something like this:

Another table

id | your_table_id | related_id

1 | 475  | value

2 | 475  | another_value